# What is the point of "final class" in Java?

Tags: java, final

I am reading a book about Java and it says that you can declare the whole class as `final`. I cannot think of anything where I'd use this.

I am just new to programming and I am wondering **if programmers actually use this on their programs**. If they do, when do they use it so I can understand it better and know when to use it.

If Java is object oriented, and you declare a class `final`, doesn't it stop the idea of class having the characteristics of objects?

Comment: A great candidate for a `final` class in Java is one that only holds `public static` constants or utilities that you want your entire project to have access to! It's effectively a namespace for those constants or utilities.

Answer (score 640, accepted):

First of all, I recommend this article: [Java: When to create a final class](http://programming.guide/java/when-to-create-a-final-class.html)

---

> **If they do, when do they use it so I can understand it better and know when to use it.**

A `final` class is simply a class that **can't be extended**.

(It does not mean that all references to objects of the class would act as if they were declared as `final`.)

When it's useful to declare a class as final is covered in the answers of this question:

- [Good reasons to prohibit inheritance in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218744/good-reasons-to-prohibit-inheritance-in-java)

> **If Java is object oriented, and you declare a class `final`, doesn't it stop the idea of class having the characteristics of objects?**

In some sense yes.

By marking a class as final you disable a powerful and flexible feature of the language for that part of the code. Some classes however, should not (and in certain cases *can* not) be designed to take subclassing into account in a good way. In these cases it makes sense to mark the class as final, even though it limits OOP. (Remember however that a final class can still extend another non-final class.)

Comment: To add to the answer, one of the principles of Effective Java is to favor composition over inheritance. The use of the final keyword also helps to enforce that principle.

Comment: "You do it mainly for efficiency and security reasons." I hear this remark quite often (even Wikipedia states this) but I still don't understand the reasoning behind this argument. Does someone care to explain how, say, a non-final java.lang.String would have ended up either inefficient or insecure?

Comment: @MRA If I create a method that accepts a String as a parameter, I assume that it's immutable, because Strings are. As a result of this, I know I can call any method on the String object safely, and not change the passed String. If I were to extend String, and change the implementation of substring to change the actual String, then the String object you expected to be immutable is no longer immutable.

Comment: @Cruncher Why not make substring `final` and leave String open for extension? This would be in keeping with the "Open-Closed Principle" mentioned in Sean Patrick Floyd's post.

Comment: @Sortofabeginner because it's not just substring. String as a CONTRACT is entirely immutable. As soon as you extend it is no longer a guarantee. When you have something like this so entrenched into a language, it's best to just not let people change that...

Comment: @Sortofabeginner And as soon as  you say you want all String methods and fields to be final, just so that you can create some class with additional functionality... At that point you might as well just create a class that has-a string and create methods that operate on that string.

Comment: @Shay final (amongst other things) is used to make an object immutable, so I wouldn't say they have nothing to do with each other. See here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html

Comment: This answer relies on an external source to provide details. You should edit the answer and include the details in case the external URL ever goes down.

Comment: "Some classes however, should not be designed to take subclassing into account in a good way.". A nice example would be the utility class, see Lomboks [@UtilityClass](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/UtilityClass) for a nice implementation.

Comment: Sometime you can implement the same interface and use delegate pattern to view and change some behavior of a final class if needed.

Answer (score 208):

In Java, items with the `final` modifier cannot be changed!

This includes final classes, final variables, and final methods:

- A final class cannot be extended by any other class
- A final variable cannot be reassigned another value
- A final method cannot be overridden

Comment: The actual question is _why_, not _what_.

Comment: The statement, "In Java, items with the `final` modifier cannot be changed!", is too categorical and, in fact, not entirely correct. As Grady Booch put it, "An object has state, behavior, and identity". While we can't change an object's identity once its reference has been marked as final, we do have a chance to change its **state** by assigning new values to its non-`final` fields (provided, of course, it has them.) Anyone who is planning to obtain an Oracle Java Certification (such as 1Z0-808, etc.) should keep this in mind because there might be questions on this aspect on the exam...

Answer (score 41):

One scenario where final is important, when you want to **prevent inheritance** of a class, for security reasons. This allows you to make sure that code you are running *cannot be overridden* by someone.

Another scenario is for optimization: I seem to remember that the Java compiler inlines some function calls from final classes. So, if you call `a.x()` and a is declared `final`, we know at compile-time what the code will be and can inline into the calling function. I have no idea whether this is actually done, but with final it is a possibility.

Comment: The inlining is normally only done by the just-in-time compiler at runtime. It works without final, too, but the JIT-compiler has a bit more work to do to be certain that there are no extending classes (or that these extending classes do not touch this method).

Comment: A good write up on the issue of inlining and optimization can be found here: http://lemire.me/blog/archives/2014/12/17/optimizing-polymorphic-code-in-java/

Comment: > cannot be overridden by someone

By who?

Comment: I think the term security is used in an almost confusing academic sense to mean safety. Safety meaning when you work with a class you know another class hasn't extended it and is relying on the internal implementations of the base class.  I think we've all been in situations where classes are extended in all sorts of nasty ways and it's impossible to reason about the code without taking out a good chunk of your day.

Answer (score 29):

The best example is

> public final class String

which is an immutable class and cannot be extended.
Of course, there is more than just making the class final to be immutable.

Comment: Hehe, sometimes it protects Rube Goldergian developers from themselves.

Answer (score 24):

If you imagine the class hierarchy as a tree (as it is in Java), abstract classes can only be branches and final classes are those that can only be leafs. Classes that fall into neither of those categories can be both branches and leafs.

There's no violation of OO principles here, final is simply providing a nice symmetry.

In practice you want to use final if you want your objects to be immutable or if you're writing an API, to signal to the users of the API that the class is just not intended for extension.

Answer (score 15):

Relevant reading: [The Open-Closed Principle](https://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/fall07/cps108/papers/ocp.pdf) by Bob Martin.

**Key quote:**

> Software Entities (Classes, Modules,
>   Functions, etc.)  should be open for
>   Extension, but closed for
>   Modification.

The `final` keyword is the means to enforce this in Java, whether it's used on methods or on classes.

Comment: @Sean: Doesn't declaring it `final` make the class closed for extension rather than open? Or am I taking it too literally?

Comment: @Goran globally applying final, yes. The key is to selectively apply final in places where you don't want modification (and of course to provide good hooks for extension)

Comment: In OCP, "modification" refers to modifying the source code, and "extension" refers to implementation inheritance. Therefore, use of `final` on a class/method declaration would not make sense if you want the implementation code to be closed for modification but open for extension by inheritance.

Comment: @Rogerio I have borrowed the reference (and the interpretation) from the [Spring Framework Reference (MVC)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html). IMHO this makes a lot more sense than the original version.

Comment: Extension is dead. Useless. Decimated. Destroyed. I don't care about OCP. There's never an excuse to extend a class.

Comment: It's to enforce that a class cannot be extended.

Comment: @KaranKhanna obviously, yes. But the reason to do that is the Open/Closed Principle.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd with final we are making the class closed for extension also and leaving no scope of improvements. A class should only be declared final when we are sure that no improvements will be required.

Comment: @KaranKhanna a) this question was not only about final on class level. Making methods final can be a clear guidance on how a class is supposed to be extended. b) The OCP can apply to an entire codebase. We can prohibit the extension of specific classes (e.g. java.lang.Integer) and still provide an extendable API (java.lang.Number).

And no, I disagree: Effective Java Item 17 says "Design and document for inheritance or else prohibit it". Final classes should be the default. One of the many cases where Java sets defaults badly.

Comment: @JoshWoodcock Could you explain how to sensibly implement exception hierarchies without extending classes? And no, abstract is not a solution, I need to be able to instantiate both specialized and non specialized errors.

Comment: @RomuloPBenedetti Why do you want hierarchies? Is one class more important than the other class? If you want to "inherit" capabilities or properties from another class just create an instance of that class in "subclass" constructor and then access its properties.

Comment: @JoshWoodcock I want a SpecializedError to be a instance of a GenericError, and want GenericError to be possibly trowed whet the error don't fit SpecializedError, as exceptions are, as the name say, exceptions. The same is valid for logging levels, concrete Inheritance is exactly for classes that are a subsets of another classes.

Comment: @JoshWoodcock if you want a more concrete example, we can have a Square inherit from Rectangle, where both can be instantiated and Square is a special case subset of Rectangle, that add some guarantees.

Comment: @RomuloPBenedetti Why do you want subsets? Why do you need the construct? That is my question. Why does something have to be a subset of a single thing?

Comment: @JoshWoodcock Because I need a polymorphic, hierarchical, subset behavior, so I can have many treatments partitioning for finer classification aware treatment, where those levels are all instantiable. Exceptions are the best example of this, because some times we want B, C and D type of exceptions to be manipulated as they are, or like the parent A , but exceptions some time are not so well defined, and we still want to be able to throw a A and guarantee it is not threaten as B, C and D. If A could be a interface or a abstract only, sure this is another history, it is not the case.

Answer (score 14):

The keyword `final` itself means something is final and is not supposed to be modified in any way. If a class if marked `final` then it can not be extended or sub-classed. But the question is why do we mark a class `final`? IMO there are various reasons:

1. **Standardization:** Some classes perform standard functions and they are not meant to be modified e.g. classes performing various functions related to string manipulations or mathematical functions etc.
2. **Security reasons**: Sometimes we write classes which perform various authentication and password related functions and we do not want them to be altered by anyone else.

I have heard that marking class `final` improves efficiency but frankly I could not find this argument to carry much weight.

> If Java is object oriented, and you declare a class final, doesn't it
>   stop the idea of class having the characteristics of objects?

Perhaps yes, but sometimes that is the intended purpose. Sometimes we do that to achieve bigger benefits of security etc. by sacrificing the ability of this class to be extended. But a final class can still extend one class if it needs to.

On a side note we should [prefer composition over inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343840/favor-composition-over-inheritance) and `final` keyword actually helps in enforcing this principle.

Answer (score 13):

**`final class` can avoid breaking the public API when you add new methods**

Suppose that on version 1 of your `Base` class you do:

```
public class Base {}
```

and a client does:

```
class Derived extends Base {
    public int method() { return 1; }
}
```

Then if in version 2 you want to add a `method` method to `Base`:

```
class Base {
    public String method() { return null; }
}
```

it would break the client code.

If we had used `final class Base` instead, the client wouldn't have been able to inherit, and the method addition wouldn't break the API.

Answer (score 10):

In java final keyword uses for below occasions.

1. **Final Variables**
2. **Final Methods**
3. **Final Classes**

> In java final variables can't reassign, **final classes** can't extends and final methods can't override.

Answer (score 9):

A final class is a class that can't be extended. Also methods could be declared as final to indicate that cannot be overridden by subclasses.

Preventing the class from being subclassed could be particularly useful if you write APIs or libraries and want to avoid being extended to alter base behaviour.

Answer (score 8):

Be careful when you make a class "final". Because if you want to write an unit test for a final class, you cannot subclass this final class in order to use the dependency-breaking technique "Subclass and Override Method" described in Michael C. Feathers' book "Working Effectively with Legacy Code". In this book, Feathers said, "Seriously, it is easy to believe that sealed and final are a wrong-headed mistake, that they should never have been added to programming languages. But the real fault lies with us. When we depend directly on libraries that are out of our control, we are just asking for trouble."

Comment: That is a technique of **legacy** code, not a technique for a *new class you are writing*, which is by definition *not* legacy code.

Answer (score 5):

If the class is marked `final`, it means that the class' structure can't be modified by anything external. Where this is the most visible is when you're doing traditional polymorphic inheritance, basically `class B extends A` just won't work. It's basically a way to protect some parts of your code *(to extent)*.

To clarify, marking class `final` doesn't mark its fields as `final` and as such doesn't protect the object properties but the actual class structure instead.

Comment: What does the object properties mean? Does it mean I could modify the member variable of the class if the class is declared final? So the only purpose of final class is to prevent inheritance.

Answer (score 5):

**TO ADDRESS THE FINAL CLASS PROBLEM:**

There are two ways to make a class final. The first is to use the keyword final in the class declaration:

```
public final class SomeClass {
  //  . . . Class contents
}
```

The second way to make a class final is to declare all of its constructors as private:

```
public class SomeClass {
  public final static SOME_INSTANCE = new SomeClass(5);
  private SomeClass(final int value) {
  }
```

Marking it final saves you the trouble if finding out that it is actual a final, to demonstrate look at  this Test class. looks public at first glance.

```
public class Test{
  private Test(Class beanClass, Class stopClass, int flags)
    throws Exception{
    //  . . . snip . . . 
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, since the only constructor of the class is private, it is impossible to extend this class. In the case of the Test class, there is no reason that the class should be final. The Test class is a good example of how implicit final classes can cause problems.

**So you should mark it final when you implicitly make a class final by making it's constructor private.**

Answer (score 4):

One advantage of keeping a class as final :-

String class is kept final so that no one can override its methods and change the functionality. e.g no one can change functionality of length() method. It will always return length of a string.

Developer of this class wanted no one to change functionality of this class, so he kept it as final.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers have focused on what `final class` tells the compiler: do not allow another class to declare it `extends` this class, and why that is desirable.

But the compiler is not the only reader of the phrase `final class`. Every **programmer** who reads the source code also reads that. It can aid rapid program comprehension.

In general, if a programmer sees `Thing thing = that.someMethod(...);` and the programmer wants to understand the subsequent behaviour of the object accessed through the `thing` object-reference, the programmer must consider the `Thing` class hierarchy: potentially many types, scattered over many packages. But if the programmer knows, or reads, `final class Thing`, they instantly know that they do not need to search for and study so many Java files, because there are no derived classes: they need study only `Thing.java` and, perhaps, it's base classes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, sometimes you may want this though, either for security or speed reasons. It's done also in C++. It may not be *that* applicable for programs, but moreso for frameworks.
http://www.glenmccl.com/perfj_025.htm

Answer (score 2):

think of FINAL as the "End of the line" - that guy cannot produce offspring anymore. So when you see it this way, there are ton of real world scenarios that you will come across that requires you to flag an 'end of line' marker to the class. It is Domain Driven Design - if your domain demands that a given ENTITY (class) cannot create sub-classes, then mark it as FINAL.

I should note that there is nothing stopping you from inheriting a "should be tagged as final" class. But that is generally classified as "abuse of inheritance", and done because most often you would like to inherit some function from the base class in your class.

The best approach is to look at the domain and let it dictate your design decisions.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have an `Employee` class that has a method `greet`. When the `greet` method is called it simply prints `Hello everyone!`. So that is the ***expected behavior*** of `greet` method

```
public class Employee {

    void greet() {
        System.out.println("Hello everyone!");
    }
}
```

Now, let `GrumpyEmployee` subclass `Employee` and override `greet` method as shown below.

```
public class GrumpyEmployee extends Employee {

    @Override
    void greet() {
        System.out.println("Get lost!");
    }
}
```

Now in the below code have a look at the `sayHello` method. It takes `Employee` instance as a parameter and calls the greet method hoping that it would say *`Hello everyone!`* But what we get is *`Get lost!`*. This change in behavior is because of `Employee grumpyEmployee = new GrumpyEmployee();`

```
public class TestFinal {
    static Employee grumpyEmployee = new GrumpyEmployee();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestFinal testFinal = new TestFinal();
        testFinal.sayHello(grumpyEmployee);
    }

    private void sayHello(Employee employee) {
        employee.greet(); //Here you would expect a warm greeting, but what you get is "Get lost!"
    }
}
```

This situation can be ***avoided*** if the `Employee` class was made `final`. Just imagine the amount of chaos a cheeky programmer could cause if `String` Class was not declared as `final`.

Answer (score 1):

As above told, if you want no one can change the functionality of the method then you can declare it as final.

Example: Application server file path for download/upload, splitting string based on offset, such methods you can declare it Final so that these method functions will not be altered. And if you want such final methods in a separate class, then define that class as Final class. So Final class will have all final methods, where as Final method can be declared and defined in non-final class.

Answer (score 1):

Final class cannot be extended further. If we do not need to make a class inheritable in java,we can use this approach.

If we just need to make particular methods in a class not to be overridden, we just can put final keyword in front of them. There the class is still inheritable.

Answer (score 0):

Final classes cannot be extended. So if you want a class to behave a certain way and don't someone to override the methods (with possibly less efficient and more malicious code), you can declare the whole class as final or specific methods which you don't want to be changed.

Since declaring a class does not prevent a class from being instantiated, it does not mean it will stop the class from having the characteristics of an object. It's just that you will have to stick to the methods just the way they are declared in the class.

Answer (score 0):

Android Looper class is a good practical example of this. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html

The Looper class provides certain functionality which is NOT intended to be overridden by any other class. Hence, no sub-class here.

Answer (score 0):

Marking a class final indicates to static analysis tools that the class could never be inherited. If a method is not throwing an exception, but the method signature says it is, the tool now has the go-ahead to warn you about it, or patch it immediately. As long as the class is not final you can say a method throws an exception even when it doesn't, since it may be that an overriding method will want to throw that exception.

The `abstract` and `final` keywords are basically achieving the same ends. I guess if they had to rewrite Java from scratch they'd probably choose one of these as the default and only have the opposing modifier.

Answer (score -1):

I know only one actual use case: generated classes

Among the use cases of generated classes, I know one: dependency inject e.g. https://github.com/google/dagger

Answer (score -3):

Object Orientation is not about inheritance, it is about encapsulation. And inheritance breaks encapsulation.

Declaring a class final makes perfect sense in a lot of cases. Any object representing a “value” like a color or an amount of money could be final. They stand on their own.

If you are writing libraries, make your classes final unless you explicitly indent them to be derived. Otherwise, people may derive your classes and override methods, breaking your assumptions / invariants. This may have security implications as well.

Joshua Bloch in “Effective Java” recommends designing explicitly for inheritance or prohibiting it and he notes that designing for inheritance is not that easy.