# assigning super class a reference java

Tags: java, inheritance, reference, superclass

I have a class Vector with a constructor

```
Vector(int dimension) // creates a vector of size dimension
```

I have a class Neuron that extends the Vector class

```
public class Neuron extends Vector {

    public Neuron(int dimension, ... other parameters in here ...) { 
         super(dimension);
         // other assignments below here ...
     }    
}
```

What I want to be able to do is assign the Vector in the Neuron class a reference to another Vector. Something along the lines of

```
    public Neuron(Vector v, ... other parameters in here ...) { 
         super = v;
         // other assignments below here ...
     }
```

Of course, I can't do this. Is there some work around? Even if I was not able to do this in the constructor of the Neuron class, that would probably be OK.

Comment: Wanting to do this is often a good indication that you should be using [composition instead of inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2399554/228171)

Comment: I wouldn't use Vector unless you have to. I would use ArrayList instead and I wouldn't sub-class it. It is better to use delegation as required.

Comment: Vector is my own class that mimics the behavior of mathematical vectors. I should have made it clear that I wasn't talking about the java.util Vector class here. However, it's more of a general question on assigning a reference to the super class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to create a [copy constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor) in the `Vector` class:

```
public Vector(Vector toCopy) {
    this.dimension = toCopy.dimension;

    // ... copy other attributes
}
```

and then in `Neuron` you do

```
public Neuron(Vector v, ... other parameters in here ...) { 
     super(v);
     // other assignments below here ...
}
```

---

You may also consider using on *composition* instead of *inheritance*. In fact, that is one of the recommendations in Effective Java. In such case you would do

```
class Neuron {
    Vector data;

    public Neuron(Vector v, ... other parameters in here ...) {
        data = v;
        // other assignments below here ...
    }
}
```

**Related questions:**

- [Difference between Inheritance and Composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399544/difference-between-inheritance-and-composition)
- [Favor composition over inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343840/favor-composition-over-inheritence)

Comment: I implemented something like that and it didn't give me exactly what I was looking for. The dimension specifies the size of the array in the Vector class. The array is the only member of the class so this is what I have:

    'public Vector(Vector toCopy) {
        this.array = toCopy.array
    }'

However, when I use the copy constructor to do 

    'Vector v2 = new Vector(v1);
    System.out.println(v1);
    System.out.println(v2);'

it prints out two different things which is different than v1 = v2. Though when I make a change to one vector it carries through to the other.

Comment: As long as you do `this.array = toCopy.array` changes to one array should affect the other too. Just avoid things such as `System.arraycopy` and you should be fine.

Comment: Interesting that you posted those links about composition vs inheritance because I was using composition before and switched to inheritance as it mad the code a bit cleaner, but maybe i should switch back.

Comment: It usually looks a bit cleaner code-wise when changing to inheritance, but it's not as flexible and easy to maintain. The rule of thumb is to use inheritance, if and only if there is a true *is-a* relationship between the classes. So, ask yourself, *is* a Neuron a Vector?