# How to properly access generic methods from parent class through a child that isn't generic?

Tags: java, swing, generics, combobox

I have this class (call it `child`) that extends the JComboBox class from the `Swing` library in Java. Now when I create an object of `child` and try to call the method `addItem(Object)` on it by passing in a `String`, I get the following warning:

```
Type safety: The method addItem(Object) belongs to the raw type JComboBox. References to generic type JComboBox<E> should be parameterized.
```

What is the proper way of invoking this method? I can't instantiate `child` with the generic type of `<String>` because `child` is not generic; I don't see how else to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

PS. Changing contents of `child` is not an option.

Comment: `class MyClass extends JComboBox<String>`

Comment: "Changing contents of `child` is not an option"

Comment: Then ignore the warning and move on. If you can't change `child`, and have to use instances of `child`, then there's nothing you can do.

Comment: You probably don't want to extend JComboBox at all but rather your class should "have-a" `JComboBox<String>`, since it is *usually* preferred to favor composition over inheritance. Please see Wikipedia article: [Composition over Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), and two StackOverflow links: [Prefer composition over inheritance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance) and [Favor composition over inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343840/favor-composition-over-inheritance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to make your child class a child of `JComboBox<String>`, not just `JComboBox`. This will stop the little warning for popping up.

Example:

```
public class Child extends JComboBox<String>{

}
```

When you do this, all the generic methods, fields and so on will now be a `String` and not an `Object`.

Edit:

I see you said that you cannot change the child class. This makes things rather difficult.

There isn't really a straightforward way of doing this, even workarounds will ultimately still display this warning. Your one option (that i can see) is use to use the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` annotation above the code producing the warning. This will stop the warning from showing up.

Comment: For some reason, the OP stated that he cannot change the child class.

Comment: @Laf Thanks for pointing that out - will edit the answer to reflect that.