# Design pattern to convert a class to another

Tags: java

I have a class called GoogleWeather, I want to convert it to another class CustomWeather.

Is there any design pattern which helps you to convert classes?

Comment: What is your hierarchy (does CustomWeather extends GoogleWeather) ?
What do you mean by "converting" ?

Comment: Convert as in how? Creating a subclass, renaming it, etc? It's unclear what you desire in the "CustomWeather" class

Comment: there is no inheritance between GoogleWeather and CustomWeather

Comment: Factory pattern here IMO. You are creating a new object (CustomWeather) and using another as the "ingredients" (GoogleWeather).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There is one critical decision to make:

*Do you need the object that is generated by the conversion to reflect future changes to the source object?*

If you do not need such functionality, then the simplest approach is to use a utility class with static methods that create a new object based on the fields of the source object, as mentioned in other answers.

On the other hand, if you need the converted object to reflect changes to the source object, you would probably need something along the lines of the [Adapter design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern):

```
public class GoogleWeather {
    ...
    public int getTemperatureCelcius() {
        ...
    }
    ...
}

public interface CustomWeather {
    ...
    public int getTemperatureKelvin();
    ...
}

public class GoogleWeatherAdapter implements CustomWeather {
    private GoogleWeather weather;
    ...
    public int getTemperatureKelvin() {
        return this.weather.getTemperatureCelcius() + 273;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: i didn't understand the difference between adapter and mapper appproche what is the advantage of using the adapter pattern in this case ?

Comment: @user1549004: The adapter is a wrapper - all methods are forwarded to the source object. That means that any updates to the source object, are propagated through the adapter. On the other hand, using a mapper class is a one-time thing - any updates to the source will not generally affect the result of the conversion.

Comment: can you please give me an example when using a mapper class in the case that any updates  to the source doesn't affect the result of the conversion.

Comment: im sorry i mean affect the result*

Comment: @user1549004: Using my example above, assume a GoogleWeather instance with a field `int temperature = 30;` Using a mapper will produce a CustomWeather instance with a field `int temperature = 303;`. If the original GW instance is modified when the temperature changes e.g. to 32, the converted CW instance will still have the old value of 303 instead of 305.

Comment: @user1549004: using an adapter on the other hand, would just pass any access to the adapter object back to the source object, thus reflecting any changes immediately.

Comment: Wasn't the question about converting?

Answer (score 66):

In that case I'd use a Mapper class with a bunch of static methods:

```
public final class Mapper {

   public static GoogleWeather from(CustomWeather customWeather) {
      GoogleWeather weather = new GoogleWeather();
      // set the properties based on customWeather
      return weather;
   }

   public static CustomWeather from(GoogleWeather googleWeather) {
      CustomWeather weather = new CustomWeather();
      // set the properties based on googleWeather
      return weather;
   }
}
```

So you don't have dependencies between the classes.

Sample usage:

```
CustomWeather weather = Mapper.from(getGoogleWeather());
```

Comment: is it a good approach to work with Mapper ?

Comment: Of cause, it is **the best approach ever**! (just kidding, but hey, I wouldn't recommend bad solutions here)

Comment: Something that should be noted: this is a one-time conversion; future changes in the source object will not affect the fields of the resulting object.

Comment: Why would you do the class final here?
(it makes the class [non-extendable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5181618/2279924), I heard)

Comment: @Patrick yes, as this is a utility class (aka global methods) declaring it final (and often also create a private constructor) should avoid wrong usage. In Java you cannot override static methods so inheritance is not useful here.

Comment: +1 for keeping the types without dependency, -1 for implementing it by  static methods making units using this not testable independent (without some crazy magic)

Comment: @ArneBurmeister I don't understand why you say this isn't testable? You can easily write a unit test for classes/methods like these.

Comment: @alex right, it is easy to test the static methods of this utility class but it would be hard to test classes using this methods as you cannot mock them easily. By not using static methods but making it normal api of the instance you could use dependency injection and mock the Mapper logic.

Comment: @ArneBurmeister I agree with that. I would only recommend this answer as an option when the developer does not have access to the class. When it is a normal API of the instance, it makes it easier to convert between objects, IDE friendly, and like you mentioned, it can be mocked. Also to use the static methods like the answer, what happens when you add other "Weather" types? What am I converting from in that regard? Not the best approach in my opinion.

Answer (score 9):

Besides, You can also use new Java8 feature 'Function' from java.util.function'.

More detailed explanation is provided in http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/016-transform-object-class-into-another-type-java8/ . Kindly have a look!

Comment: this is only a simple one way converter - valid but you can implement this exactly the same way in any Java version.