# StackTrace : StackTraceElement Customization

Tags: java, stack-trace

I want to customize hashcode of  [`StackTraceElement` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html) . My problem is how to use this new customized class instead of default StackTraceElement class of JVM.

Comment: But [StackTraceElement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html) is final Class.

Comment: What customisations do you want to perform?

Comment: Yes it's final I had noticed it Thanks. But what all customization I want is modifying the hashcode generation process.

Comment: Careful now! If you tell us more, we might actually help you with your problem ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to customize the StackTraceElement class by extending it

[StackTraceElement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html) is `final` and hence can not be extended.

If you (for whatever reason) want to customize the way a stack trace is printed, you can implement a utility method which takes the `Throwable` and then uses the various methods from `StackTraceElement` to create your own layout, something like

```
public static void printCustomizedTrace(Throwable t) {
   for(StackTraceElement e : t.getStackTrace()) {
      System.err.println(" => " + e.getFileName() + ":" + e.getLineNumber());
   }
}
```

You could also use **delegation** and create a list of `CustomStackTraceElements`, and implement additional logic (like different `hashmap()`) in the `CustomStackTraceElement` class:

```
public static List<CustomStackTraceElement> getCustomizedStackTrace(Throwable t) {
   List<CustomStackTraceElement> result = new ArrayList<>();

   for(StackTraceElement e : t.getStackTrace()) {
      result.add(new CustomStackTraceElement(e));
   }

   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

StackTraceElement is a final class. Final classes can't be extended.

Look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29) adn [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181578/use-of-final-class-in-java)