# android - why is ActionBar always defined as final?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Just wondering. In any code snippet I saw (also ADT-generated code) the `ActionBar` is qualified as **final**. In my app I do not use the `final` qualifier for the `ActionBar` and everything's fine. Any information/links on that topic?

Comment: Can you give an example code snippet you're referring to? A code snippet from the official docs would be best.

Comment: well the best example is creating an Activity with ActionBar using the Eclipse ADT plugin. It always defines the ActionBar as final and I'm just curious why. I guess some sites where I saw the same could not be called a reliable source

Comment: Making a variable as `final` turns it in a constant. That means you can't set a new value to your `ActionBar` type variable.

Comment: @yugidroid you don't say, mate?^^ I know what final means, just curious why it's used pretty often when handling with an ActionBar

Comment: @Maver1ck The reason I asked for code is because you usually don't "create the action bar", you extend an activity that uses an `ActionBar`, such as `ActionBarActivity`. `final` in this case is just making your activity non-extendable, then the question is just similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181578/use-of-final-class-in-java