# Difference Between final class and static class

Tags: java

I know a java a little bit , have used final and static multiple times , But I am quiet confused here : What is the basic difference between a final class A and a static class B. I know these keywords . Just could not imagine the use of final in a class declaration.

Comment: What parts of their definition are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181578/use-of-final-class-in-java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class

Comment: Oops.. looks like someone is doing the googling for you...

Comment: Thanks ! the above  linked made it clear   simple enough .I scrolled down the scroll bar and found  nothing duplicating while posting this QA .thanks for bearing it :).

Comment: The difference is that they are not the same. If you don't understand what 'static' or 'final' mean, just say so, or better still look them up.

Comment: @EJP final in a variable fixes its value , final in a method does not allow it to be overloading . their is a significant difference of its characteristic depending on where it is being used . I never had the case where I create a final class.So lacked some practice may be

Comment: I know what 'final' means. The problem here is actually that *you* don't. That's the real question. Not 'what is the difference ...'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Final class : In simple words is a class that cannot be extended . 
 - It is generally useful for writing classes to be immutable e.g. String class that is generally done for security

Static class : Static classes can only be used in case of nested classes. 
 - Nested static class doesn't need reference of Outer class but non static nested class needs it