# What does it mean if a static inner class is also final?

Tags: java, static, inner-classes, final

```
public class ClassWithInnerClass {

    int a = 10;

    public static void outer(){
        System.out.println("In method of outer class");

    }


        final static class Inner{

            int b = 20;

            public void innermethod(){
                System.out.println("In method of inner class");
                System.out.println("Inner class variable b = "+b);

            }
        }
}
```

In the above code, i have an outer class and then there is a static nested class with the non-access specifier 'final'.Does this make this class similar to "Constant" variables?

Comment: final for classes mean, than you cannot derive from that class.

Comment: Simply put, it means that `Inner` cannot be extended.

Comment: Don't confuse _inner class_ with _nested class_.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181578/use-of-final-class-in-java

Comment: Also, it doesn't matter whether the class modified with `final` is nested or not. The behavior is the same.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not similar to constant variable. It means that you can't create a sub-class of this nested class (`Inner`). This is similar to using the final keyword in top level (i.e. not nested) classes.

Answer (score 0):

`final` on classes mean that they cannot be extended. It's no different from having `final` on a class defined at the top level.

`final` on classes is *not* the same as `final` on variables. `final` has different meanings based on where you use it. In general it describes a sort of immutability:

- On variables, it means that you cannot change its value once initialized.
- On methods, it means that once defined, it cannot be overridden in a subclass.
- On classes, it means that the class itself cannot be subclassed.