# How to extend Collectors class

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

Why `Collectors` class is final in Java 8? I want to extend Collectors class in my own class `MyCollectors`. There I will add additional methods which is not existing available in `Collectors` class.

Comment: Hey my question is not use of final class in java. Please go through my question. I want to extend Collectors class into MyCollectors class.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181578/what-is-the-point-of-final-class-in-java does not solves my problem

Comment: Prasath, I have read your question. The simple, quick answer is: **You simply can't extend `Collectors`**. The longer answer, is that your question has little-to-no value for the community, since the **explanation** of *"why can't final classes have any children ?"* (classes that inherit from Collectors in this case) is explained in the aforementioned [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5181618/8075923). Eran's solution below should be satisfactory for you to understand why your initial logic was flawed.

Comment: There’s nothing stopping you from creating a class named `MyCollectors` and adding `Collector` factory method to it. What benefit should subclassing `Collectors` have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Collectors` is final because it only contains `static` utility methods. It cannot be instantiated (its constructor is `private`), and therefore there would be no meaning to sub-classing it.

You can create your own `MyCollectors` class independent of `Collectors`. 
Or if you want to access `Collectors` methods via your `MyCollectors`, you can create wrappers of all the `Collectors` static methods within your `MyCollectors` class.

Comment: Yes I want to access Collectors methods via MyCollectors methods. Wrappers means do you want me to copy all the methods from Collectors class to MyCollectors class ?

Comment: @Prasath It means copy the method signatures and have the MyCollectors methods call the corresponding Collectors methods. I wouldn't do that, though, since it seems pointless to me.

Comment: What happens if they added another new method in collectors class in next update? Do I need to do the same in MyCollectors class? If yes, then is any other solutions to my problem?

Comment: @Prasath As I said, I wouldn't do that wrapping. Just use the two classes (`Collectors` and `MyCollectors`) together. You don't need a single class to contain all the collectors utility methods.

Comment: Ok I will keep my methods alone in MyCollectors class.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to implement your own collector, it is not about subclassing `Collectors` utility class, but about creating classes implementing `Collector` interface. As answered by Eran above

> You can create your own MyCollectors class independent of Collectors. Or if you want to access Collectors methods via your MyCollectors, you can create wrappers of all the Collectors static methods within your MyCollectors class.

you can create your own class with methods returning your own implementation of `Collector`