# If array of wildcards is forbidden, what types can I use?

Tags: java

*Wildcard is an abstract type. It's impossible to instantiate it.* So I understand that the following instantiation of a class

```
ArrayList< ? extends String> list= new ArrayList< ? extends String>(); // won't work
```

So what types can work ? Any that aren't abstract ?

Comment: There is no class that extends `String` since `String` class is `final`.

Comment: How did you get to this code? What do you want to do with `list`?

Comment: @ernest_k From the [slides of my lecture](https://snag.gy/v8mrTS.jpg) (I hate slides)

Answer (score 0):

String is final class, so you cannot extend from it !

check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5181618/7366850

for more examples on wildcard check:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/wildcards-in-java/