# Why was java.time.YearMonth made a final class?

Tags: java, class, java-stream, final, java-time

I planned to write a class that `extends java.time.YearMonth` with the purpose to extend the `YearMonth` with a method that enables me to stream the `LocalDate`s of that `YearMonth`:

```
public class ExtendedYearMonth extends YearMonth {

    public Stream<LocalDate> days() {
        LocalDate firstOfMonth = this.atDay(1);
        LocalDate lastOfMonth = firstOfMonth.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
        return firstOfMonth.datesUntil(lastOfMonth);
    }
}
```

Well, that plan instantly failed when I found `YearMonth` to be a `final class` ⇒ *`final class`es are not extensible*.

I could of course write a class like this one

```
public class ExtendedYearMonth {
    private YearMonth yearMonth;

    // parameterized constructor, getters and setters omitted for brevity

    public Stream<LocalDate> days() {
        LocalDate firstOfMonth = this.yearMonth.atDay(1);
        LocalDate lastOfMonth = firstOfMonth.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
        return firstOfMonth.datesUntil(lastOfMonth);
    }
}
```

but that's not what I wanted because it requires me to instantiate a `YearMonth` and an `ExtendedYearMonth` just to `stream` (and `filter`, the main purpose) the `LocalDate`s of a specific month in a specific year.

The [JavaDocs of `YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) just state **that** it's `final`, but not **why** it is `final`:

> `public final class YearMonth`
> ...
> YearMonth is an immutable date-time object that represents the combination of a year and month.
> ...

## Why was `YearMonth` made `final`?

Or more accurate : What's the benefit of `final class YearMonth` over a `class YearMonth`?
I cannot imagine any reason...

I know, to answer this one is required to have insight to the design decisions that may be public somewhere in the www, but, unfortunatley, I don't have this insight and I haven't found a source so far.

In Kotlin, this doesn't matter because one can write an extension function without having to inherit from that `class`. That's a nice feature of Kotlin, but Java doesn't have this (for now) and I refuse to write a wrapper class for this.

I could also ask why such a method isn't available in `YearMonth` or wasn't added when `LocalDate` got `datesUntil` in Java 9, but that would be a second question in a single post, which is generally frowned (and down- or close-voted) upon, so I may ask that later in a different post.

My current solution is a `public static Stream<LocalDate> daysOf(YearMonth yearMonth)` which does what the above code does, but I have to pass an instance to a `static` method instead of directly using a method of it. That's working for my requirement, but it's still not what I consider a near-to-perfection solution.

Comment: Well it's supposed to be immutable. A non-final class cannot guarantee that its instances are immutable.

Comment: I think this question can be generalized into "[What is the point of final classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181578/what-is-the-point-of-final-class-in-java)"

Comment: Well, @MCEmperor, having read this again, even I think so, too, now. I may delete it when I am back at a computer and ask a different one, one that cannot be easily generalised...

Comment: [What is the point of “final class” in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181578/what-is-the-point-of-final-class-in-java)

Comment: You could move `days()` to a `YearMonths` non-instantiable utility class, which is `final` and has a `private` constructor.

Comment: About all of the classes of java.time (the modern Java date and time API) are value-based and therefore immutable and therefore final.

Comment: `datesUntil` is exclusive, so you will want to pass the 1st of the following month to it.

Comment: I concede that this is a duplicate, but the answers to the original question are not at all convincing.

Comment: I am wondering what must have prompted someone to d o w n v o t e such a great question.

Comment: It can be interpreted as a duplicate... The answer is basically the comment given by @OleV.V.: *About all of the classes of java.time (the modern Java date and time API) are value-based and therefore immutable and therefore final.* But I still want to have some stream API methods like the mentioned `days()`, using a correct implementation then, of course ;-) `firstOfMonth.datesUntil(firstOfMonth.plusMonths(1))`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The documentation of `YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) does say it, but indirectly:

> This is a [value-based](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/doc-files/ValueBased.html) class; use of identity-sensitive operations (including reference equality (`==`), identity hash code, or synchronization) on instances of `YearMonth` may have unpredictable results and should be avoided.

Whereas [value-based](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/doc-files/ValueBased.html) says:

> #### Value-based Classes
>
> Some classes, such as `java.util.Optional` and `java.time.LocalDateTime`, are value-based. Instances of a value-based class:
>
> - are final and immutable (though may contain references to mutable objects);
> - have implementations of `equals`, `hashCode`, and `toString` which are computed solely from the instance's state and not from its identity or the state of any other object or variable;
> - make no use of identity-sensitive operations such as reference equality (`==`) between instances, identity hash code of instances, or synchronization on an instances's intrinsic lock;
> - are considered equal solely based on `equals()`, not based on reference equality (`==`);
> - do not have accessible constructors, but are instead instantiated through factory methods which make no committment as to the identity of returned instances;
> - are *freely substitutable* when equal, meaning that interchanging any two instances `x` and `y` that are equal according to `equals()` in any computation or method invocation should produce no visible change in behavior.
>
> A program may produce unpredictable results if it attempts to distinguish two references to equal values of a value-based class, whether directly via reference equality or indirectly via an appeal to synchronization, identity hashing, serialization, or any other identity-sensitive mechanism. Use of such identity-sensitive operations on instances of value-based classes may have unpredictable effects and should be avoided.

It’s not stated explicitly here, but subclassing would contradict these points, as it would lead to the possibility of instances representing the same value (in terms of the baseclass’ state), but not be freely substitutable, when they don’t have the same type. Also, even when the class was not `final`, the concept of only providing factory methods returning instances of unspecified identity would not allow subclasses, as subclasses require an accessible constructor.

You may see value-based classes as an equivalent to primitive values; you can’t subclass an `int`, so you can’t subclass a `YearMonth`, as it only represents a specific value (just strongly typed) and all `YearMonth` instances representing the same value are supposed to be the same, whether represented by different object instances or a single instance. This keeps the path open to a future with real value types in Java.

Answer (score 3):

Because instances of the class are guaranteed to be **immutable**.

That guarantee could not be made if subclasses were allowed.

From the [YearMonth class documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html):

```
* {@code YearMonth} is an immutable date-time object that represents the combination
* of a year and month.
```

Comment: That's it? Why was that guaranteed?

Comment: The documentation also notes that instances are *thread-safe*. Immutable objects are inherently thread-safe.

Comment: By the way, good coverage of the advantages of immutable classes is provided by Joshua Bloch in *Effective Java* in "Item 15: Minimize Mutability."