# About final class

Tags: java

When we declare all variables and methods in a class as final, we are restricted the concept of override.

Then, "what is the reason we want to restrict IS-A relationship in an OOP language( even we restrict IS-A relationship, this language has Has-A relationship) by using final class?"

My point is we can not restrict the accessing the members of our class any way, then give an easy access by allowing IS-A relationship.
Otherwise it is a headache to create objects and all? (in my view 'access' not includes  modifications)

If I miss any important theme of programming , please excuse me. And tell me, what is it?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any necessity to declare a class as final class?

Necessity, no. Declare a class final if you want to forbid extending it.
This can prevent programming errors.
For example it's a recommended practice to make utility classes with only static methods to be final,
as inheriting from such class wouldn't make sense,
and be clearly a programming error.

Answer (score 1):

Security would be one necessity. String class in Java is an Immutable/final class. No sub-classing is possible System class is another example.

Have more read here:
[Good reasons to prohibit inheritance in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218744/good-reasons-to-prohibit-inheritance-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any necessity to declare a class as final class?

Yes. If you are implementing a [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) with a `class`. If someone can sub-class your Singleton, then there may be more than one (which violates the Singleton pattern).