# what are the project related scenarios in which we have to make a class Final in java?

Tags: java, class, final

What will be the scenario in a real project to specially use the Final Class?

**P.S:** Final Class is for preventing the class from sub-classing that class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Good reasons to prohibit inheritance in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218744/good-reasons-to-prohibit-inheritance-in-java)

Comment: at what stage in our project design we can use final class